# Data is not loading in ExtJS 3.4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

My new in extjs and working on ExtJS 3.2.

In that my data is not loading but if comment data column is displaying can anyone please help me.

> My code is

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: "Search Result",
    items: [{
        xtype: 'grid',
        store: new Ext.data.Store({
            autoDestroy: true,
            fields: ['Name', 'Roll', 'Class'],
            root: 'records',
            // proxy: proxy,
            data: [{
                Name: false,
                Roll: 'a',
                Class: 20
            }, {
                Name: true,
                Roll: 'b',
                Class: 25
            }]
        }),
        columns: [{
            text: 'Name',
            id: 'company',
            header: 'Name',
            width: 130,
            sortable: false,
            hideable: false,
            dataIndex: 'Name'
        }, {
            text: 'Roll',
            width: 130,
            header: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'Roll',
            hidden: false
        }, {
            text: 'Class',
            width: 130,
            header: 'Class',
            dataIndex: 'Class',
            hidden: false
        }]
    }]

}
```

Inside panel I am taking grid.

Can anybody please help me.?

Answer (score 1):

I am writing data outside the scope and now its working fine.

My complete code is.

```
var myData = [       
    ['FFPE Slide',2,'eSample'],
    ['Plasma',2,'eSample'],
    ['Whole Blood',2,'eSample']  ];   

// create the data store
var store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    fields: [
       {name: 'stype'},
       {name: 'scnt'},
       {name: 'src'}

    ]
});
store.loadData(myData);  
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: store,
    columns: [
        {id:'company',header: "Sample Type", width: 75, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'stype'},
        {header: "Subjects Count", width: 75, sortable: true,  dataIndex: 'scnt'},
        {header: "Source", width: 75, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'src'}
    ],
    stripeRows: true,
    autoExpandColumn: 'company',
    height:150,
    width:150,
    title:'Detailed Counts'
});
```

This is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the root config (root:'records') in the store.. or try to add records property to the data object. Remove the reader as well

Comment: Thanks. I remove `root` and `reader`. result is same. In debugger I am getting error inside 1st data

Comment: Remove comma after data array

Comment: The problem is If I place data [] then page itself is not loading. I remove comma too. No Syntax error.